# How to convert date and time into datetime/timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to import some CSV data and they have a date field and a time field of the format below

```
{"date"=>"23/04/16", "day"=>"SATURDAY", "time"=>"17:06"}
```

and i want to make that a timestamp and be the created_at field in the record.

What is the way to go about it?

Comment: Hello, where are you stuck exactly ? (DateTime.parse and DateTime.strptime would be my guess [DateTime doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html))

Comment: **Caution:** the time zone information is required to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `strptime` on `Time` or `DateTime`

if you need timestamp:

```
require 'time'

csv_hash = {"date"=>"23/04/16", "day"=>"SATURDAY", "time"=>"17:06"}
time_from_csv = Time.strptime("#{csv_hash["date"]}:#{csv_hash["time"]}", '%d/%m/%y:%H:%M') # 2016-04-23 17:06:00 +0000
timestamp = time_from_csv.to_i # 1461423960
```

Take a read at the documentation for [Time#strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime)

If you want `DateTime` do `DateTime.strptime(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
params = {"date"=>"23/04/16", "day"=>"SATURDAY", "time"=>"17:06"}

"#{params['date']} params['time']".to_datetime
```

Thanks